# Update TFS Web with a Python script

Tags: json, web, tfs, python-3.8

How can I update a certain field in tfs web with Python?

I have connected to tfs and have received an HTML response.

I have a json with the data that I would like to insert to tfs testCases field.

**JSON:**

```
data = json.loads(url.read().decode()) (Json external data)
```

**HTML:**

```
tfsResponse = requests.get(tfsApi, auth=HttpNtlmAuth(username, password))
if tfsResponse.ok:
    print(tfsResponse)

soup = BeautifulSoup(tfsResponse.text, 'lxml')
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

It's not able to directly use Jenkins automation tests results to update TFS test case.

You need use Rest API to handle this.  You need to extract the test results fist then update them to TFS server.

With using below Rest API:

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results?api-version=5.1
```

Sample body

```
 [
      {
        "state": "Completed",
        "testPoint": {
          "id": 10
        },
        "outcome": "Passed",
        "testCase": {
          "id": 4567
        }
      }
    ]
```

If you want to use code, a code snippet for your reference, should similar to Python:

```
try
{
     var u = new Uri("https://{My Account}.visualstudio.com");
     VssCredentials c = new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, "PAT"));
     var connection = new VssConnection(u, c);
     var testClient = connection.GetClient<TestManagementHttpClient>();
     int testpointid = 1;
     string teamProject = "MyProjectName";
     RunCreateModel run = new RunCreateModel(name: "TestCase Name", plan: new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.WebApi.ShallowReference("TestPlan Id"), pointIds: new int[] { testpointid });
     TestRun testrun = testClient.CreateTestRunAsync(run, teamProject).Result;

     TestCaseResult caseResult = new TestCaseResult() { State = "Completed", Outcome = "passed", Id = 100000 };

     var testResults = testClient.UpdateTestResultsAsync(new TestCaseResult[] { caseResult }, teamProject, testrun.Id).Result;
     RunUpdateModel runmodel = new RunUpdateModel(state: "Completed");
     TestRun testRunResult = testClient.UpdateTestRunAsync(runmodel, teamProject, testrun.Id, runmodel).Result;

}
catch (AggregateException e)
{
     Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException.Message);
}
```